# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS need to stop ipv6 router solicitation

Tags: ipv6

I have 2 lab systems that have no connection to the outside world. We don't have an ipv6 infrastructure in our lab. We have no need for ipv6. The machines are connected to three networks, one is a 1GbE network the other two are 10-GbE networks. Both use simple unmanaged switches. They are essentially a HPC cluster. We are forced into using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on this setup because one of the machines is only supported in that release by the vendor.

The problem we are facing is that our networks are just flooded by router solicitation packets. We decided to start by solving for just one interface.

We tried to disable ipv6 through sysctl.conf by adding

```
 net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.enp2s0.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

That seems to make the ipv6 addresses and such go away and all sorts of ways to check whether ipv6 is active show it isn't. /proc/net/inet_if6 is a blank file. sysctl -a returns

net.ipv6.conf.enp2s0.disable_ipv6 = 1

We also added the following line to /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1"
```

But the router solicitation packets kept flowing. So we then went and added things the mighty Google says should stop this behavior to /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.enp2s0.autoconf = 0

net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.enp2s0.forwarding = 0

net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 0 <tried 1 here as well. Anything but 2 should work>
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_ra = 0
```

But they keep marching on out. tcpdump shows a constant chain of:

```
12:06:45.860057 IP6 ubuntu18 > ip6-allrouters: ICMP6, router solicitation, length 8
```

On a 1 GbE this traffic is at about 640 Mbits/s!

We have to be missing something, but can't figure it out. Maybe someone has an idea.

net.ipv6.conf.enp2s0.accept_ra = 0

Comment: weird. i have only ever done the grub method to disable ipv6. I have been running tcpdump on a 18.04 computer for a few hours but see nothing like what you describe. Are your computers servers or desktops?

Comment: Could you provide a short packet dump of this traffic?

Comment: It’s configured as a desktop and we’ve added the GNU development tools, gsl, tcl8.5, tk8.5, blt2.5, fftw3.3.8. We run the same config under CentOS with no issues.

Comment: Vidarlo. Will do as soon as I get to work.